# MySql Where AND OR Conditions, returns all data?

Tags: mysql

I have a small query that uses 'And' once with 'Or' twice, as soon as I add the second Or it returns all data, not the filtered. Basically the below should return all cases for John Smith where status is either 'Active' or 'In Contact'

```
Select
c.Adviser,
l.Status
From
tbl_lead l Inner Join
tbl_clients c On c.client_id = l.client_id
Where
(c.Adviser = 'John Smith' And  l.Status = 'active') Or
(l.Status = 'in contact')
```

Can anyone see where I am going wrong at all?

Comment: no idea. you'd have to show sample table data. most likely your data is structured so that your where clause DOES cover all possibilities, so it's effectively not filtering at all.

Comment: Just a heads up: `and` binds stronger than `or` so writing something like `(x = 'Foo' and y = 'Bar') or (z = 'Yeah!')` is the same as `x = 'Foo' and y = 'Bar' or (z = 'Yeah!')`. The parentheses have no effect. Also, putting parentheses around nothing more than a comparison has no effect either. So the entire clause is basically `x = 'Foo' and y = 'Bar' or z = 'Yeah!'`. And, as stated in @faheem-farhan's answer, when you have an `or` for the same column, you should use `in`.

Comment: Parentheses need to be around the ORed expressions c.Adviser = 'John Smith' And  (l.Status = 'active' Or
l.Status = 'in contact')

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `"IN"` clause.

```
Select
c.Adviser,
l.Status
From
tbl_lead l Inner Join
tbl_clients c On c.client_id = l.client_id
Where
c.Adviser = 'John Smith' And  l.Status IN ('active','in contact')
```

Comment: was writing the same answer :)